# FIELDPROC parameter parsing

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpgle

I am trying to pass parameter to FIELDPROC prgram in the ALTER statement.

```
ALTER TABLE SEKAR2/FPPEM ALTER COLUMN S1ESSN          
SET FIELDPROC SEKAR2/KYR001('SEKAR2','FPPEM','S1ESSN')
```

Inside the program the parameters seems to be limited by a specific delimiter. I tried scanning for the character in RPGLE. It doesn't work. Please help me parse the passed parameters.

```
 ....5...10...15...20...25...30...35...40...45...50...55...60  
'SEKAR2     D                                          FPPEM ' 
'    D                                          S1ESSN       '
```

DDS definition. I am testing FIELDPROC on both DDL and DDS based files,

```
A          R FPREM                                               
A            S1EMNO         7A         COLHDG('EMPLOYEE NUMBER') 
A            S1EMNM        50A         COLHDG('EMPLOYEE NAME')   
A            S1EMTY        30A         COLHDG('EMPLOYEE TYPE')   
A            S1ESSN         9A         COLHDG('EMPLOYEE SSN')
```

Comment: Were you able to find the [documentation in the Knowledge Center?](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/sqlp/rbafyfieldproc.htm)

Comment: @jmarkmurphy I followed it and ended up https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/sqlp/rbafyfpfppvl.htm page. But it doesn't give information about porsing the input.

Comment: You don't need to parse the inputs, the link tells you the structure of the parameters. There is a whole section on how to write a field procedure. Either you are going to have to read it and learn how to do it, or I am going to have to read it and learn how to do it so I can tell you. I'm going to let you do the work.

Comment: What is the create table statement for table FPPEM?

Comment: @mike I have added the table definition in the original post